# Implementing sasl SCRAM-SHA-256 machenism with kafka-node

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, sasl-scram

How to configure sasl SCRAM-SHA-256 mechanism with kafka-node? does kafka-node support this authentication mechanism?

If no, then is there an alternative option to connect to kafka with nodejs